# How do I use "AND" operator with multiple query parameters in nested relation when querying in Prisma?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, prisma, prisma2

Its my first time trying prisma and am stuck. So I have "products" and "filters" model.

I want the following query to work. The idea is, I want to fetch the products with dynamic matching query params (name and value). The product query parameters come dynamically from the frontend.

```
const products = await prisma.product.findMany({
        where: {
          categoryName,
          subCategoryName,
          filters: {
            some: {
              AND: [
                {
                  name: "RAM",
                  value: "32GB",
                },
                {
                  name: "Storage",
                  value: "1TB",
                },
              ],
            },
          },
        },
        include: {
          images: true,
        },
      });
```

If there's only one parameter, like

```
{
  name:"RAM",
  value:"32GB"
}
```

the query returns appropriate products, but if there are more that one query params (like in the original code above), it returns empty array.

my product schema looks like this, simplified,

```
  name                      String      
  filters                   Filter[]
```

my filter schema looks like this, simplified

```
  name                      String      
  value                     String?
  product                   Product?    @relation(fields: [productId], references:[id])
  productId                 Int?
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 11):

I've found the solution here
https://github.com/prisma/prisma/discussions/8216#discussioncomment-992302

It should be like this instead apparently.

```
await prisma.product.findMany({
      where: {
        AND: [
          { price: 21.99 },
          { filters: { some: { name: 'ram', value: '8GB' } } },
          { filters: { some: { name: 'storage', value: '256GB' } } },
        ],
      },
})
```

Comment: Would you mind telling me how to avoid returning duplicates while using this where query? Let's say a piece of data matches both filters, in this case it gets returned twice.

Comment: @Dipzera try to use findFirst maybe?